# Animate clicked div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have 3 divs with `"left"` , `"active"` and `"right"` that look like this:
[image]

...now, whenever I click the left div, it animates and becomes active and the active one takes it's place, I need it to do the same for the right div also. Basically I need a way to make the side divs become active after someone clicks on them and the previous active div to take it's place as left or right div depending on which one is clicked.

For that I also wanted to change the class names so that when you click on the left div, it animates in center and I tried adding `$(this).removeClass('left').addClass('active');` and the other way around for the active div but it didn't work, it didn't switch the classes between them.

This is what I have so far [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/4xh4reho/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need different classes, you could just use one class `box` and style them using CSS's `:last-of-type` and `:nth-of-type()` selectors.

In jQuery you could animate the `div`s according to their `left` value.

<kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xh4reho/7/)**</kbd>

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  if ($(this).css('left') != '125px') {
    var l = ($(this).css('left') == '0px') ? 0 : 400;
    $(this).animate({
      width: 250,
      height: 250,
      left: 125,
      top: 0,
      opacity: 1
    }, 400);
    $('.active').animate({
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      left: l,
      top: 75,
      opacity: 0.3
    }, 400);
    $('#header > .box').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
#header {
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 75px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.box:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  top: 0;
  left: 125px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.box:last-of-type {
  left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box active"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this is strange, I just checked out your profile due to an answer you gave some time ago where you were replying you were not a "sir" :)) Anyway, this works great :D Thanks, this will do just fine ^^

Comment: PS: Also, when you edited your answer with the new jsfiddle link something broke, page can't be found, anyway, I got it :) Have a great day

Comment: It's ok, also, if I remember correctly using nth-of-type will cause issues in IE8...is there a way around it ? Or I'll just have to deal with it ?:))

Comment: @Alin - Yes, it has a [Partial Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) on IE8. If you want support for IE8, you could add `.left` and `.right` classes alongwith `.box` and style the `div`s that way. You wouldn't have to make any changes to the jQuery code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68133/discussion-between-alin-and-chipchocolate-py).